# Magento 2 import adds info but the import process doesn't end

Tags: magento2.2, price, import, products, csv

it's basically what the title says, and I'm only facing this issue when adding prices to products via csv import. I've already checked memory_limit, post_max_size values and they are good, because I made an import (creation of those products with their category and all the info but the price) of 9000+ products and I got the success message, but with this CSV of prices I don't get any success message, it gets stuck on "please wait" and it never ends, but the information it's added. Can someone give me any idea on how to face this issue? thanks

Comment: I have found that this issue only happens in the production environment, in DEV and QA it works just fine (the only differences are that the Production environment has ssl [https] and that we're using a module for google analytics [WeltPixel]) Can someone with this new info give me a hand with this?

Comment: I have discarded the reason to be the Analytics module, I installed it on the DEV environment and the import process ends succesfully. Is it something with the SSL for the server?